# Animation from bottom to center, then rotate to 45°

Tags: after-effects, animation

Tell me that I'd better use. From below, a diamond should emerge and be placed in the center. then it turns by 45° and increases in size and becomes a square. I created layers in Photoshop. on one - a diamond in the center. on the second - a square in the center with enlarged dimensions. then imported psd in after effects. And... What should I do next? Have I made the layers correctly?

Comment: Hi - please add some screenshots - you'll get better answers.

Comment: Your next step is to go to a library and get a book on animating in After Effects, or go to youtube and watch some of the gazillions of AE tutorials. Come back when you've done some basic research and have a specific question, and we'll be super glad to help.

Comment: @stib, sorry :( I already know how to make basic animation and create first AE video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a square shape.  Center it to the screen using align.
2. Move the time indicator forward in the timeline.
3. Go into the transform of the shape layer, and keyframe the position, rotation, and scale, by clicking the little stopwatch next to each of these.
4. Go back in the time line and move the object down to the bottom, by dragging or lowering the Y value under position.
5. Go passed the first point you made in the timeline when you keyframed and you should already see the shape moving up.   Now just increase scale size.
6. Adjust keyframes to the timing you want.

That's the basic premise.

Comment: scale changes Y position and after encreasing bounds square lift to bottom

Comment: Manipulate scale on the shape object, not the layer.